# IDisposable for convenience?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'm looking at implementing `IDisposable` for a transaction-like class I am creating. All of the MSDN documentation I have read mentions that `IDisposable` should be used for freeing unmanaged resources, not necessarily talking about the convenience and tidiness of not having a try-catch-finally around everything.

All of what I want to do deals with managed resources, but I do want the `Dispose()` method to effectively perform a rollback if nothing was committed before it was called - is there anything wrong with using it for this purpose?

Comment: "Transaction-like class"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265841/how-to-create-a-class-that-works-with-transactionscope

Comment: Note: More generally, you can certainly implement IDisposable() for purposes other than releasing unmanaged resources.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I know about TransactionScope but had read a few posts about how it is a bit flakey for purely C# objects - looking more closely, those links are all a bit dated.

Comment: And thanks @EricJ. you answered my question and the link was very useful. Just need to redirect my unit tests and move my code :)

Comment: well C# doesnt have transactional memory

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/6cfc842d-1c16-4739-afaf-edb35f544384/default.aspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#C.23